# Write data in file

Tags: java

I found this example how to read binary file from PostgreSQL.

```
conn.setAutoCommit(false);

        // Get the Large Object Manager to perform operations with
        LargeObjectManager lobj = ((org.postgresql.PGConnection) conn).getLargeObjectAPI();

        ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT FILE FROM KNOWLEDGEBASE_FILES WHERE ID = ?");
        ps.setInt(1, 333);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next())
        {
            // Open the large object for reading
            long oid = rs.getLong(1);
            LargeObject obj = lobj.open(oid, LargeObjectManager.READ);

            // Read the data
            byte buf[] = new byte[obj.size()];
            obj.read(buf, 0, obj.size());
            // Do something with the data read here


            FileChannel rwChannel = new RandomAccessFile("License_Agreement.pdf", "rw").getChannel();
            ByteBuffer wrBuf = rwChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, buffer.length * number_of_lines);
            for (int i = 0; i < obj.size(); i++)
            {
                wrBuf.put(obj);
            }

            // Close the object
            obj.close();
        }
        rs.close();
        ps.close();

        // Finally, commit the transaction.
        conn.commit();
```

How I can write the data into file using NIO?

At this line `wrBuf.put(obj);` I get error:

no suitable method found for put(LargeObject)
    method ByteBuffer.put(byte) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; LargeObject cannot be converted to byte)
    method ByteBuffer.put(ByteBuffer) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; LargeObject cannot be converted to ByteBuffer)
    method ByteBuffer.put(byte[]) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; LargeObject cannot be converted to byte[])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [LargeObject::getInputStream](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/largeobject/LargeObject.html#getInputStream()):

```
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
//...
while (rs.next())
{
    long oid = rs.getLong(1);
    LargeObject obj = lobj.open(oid, LargeObjectManager.READ);
    Path targetPath = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("License_Agreement.pdf");
    Files.copy(obj.getInputStream(), targetPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    obj.close();
}
```

Comment: For some reason the file is not created after I run the code.

Comment: the file is not writeable, has the user the necessary rights? did you get a stacktrace?

Comment: Yes, there are no write restrictions

Comment: I found the problem. How I can configure the Java code to write in JUnit resource directory - src\test\resources

Comment: this should do it: `FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("src/test/resources", "License_Agreement.pdf");` (see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getPath(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String...))